# Show device specific div

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, 2d, host, airconsole

When the game starts, I need to show the start game button to the first connected player and the waiting text to the second player, but it shows the waiting text to both players, how can I solve it?

Oyun başladığında ilk bağlanan oyuncuya oyunu başlat butonunu, ikinci oyuncuya da bekleme yazısını göstermem gerekiyor ama her iki oyuncuya da bekleme yazısını gösteriyor, bunu nasıl çözebilirim

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing? The first player currently has a play button. If he presses this button, the controller comes up, but the second player does not, how can I do this? –

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively straight forward to achieve.
What you want to do is have your controller.html check if the controller is the master controller using airconsole.getMasterControllerDeviceId().
The following is a minimal example of how to decide if you are the on the master controller that drives the experience or another controller:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.airconsole.com/api/airconsole-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var airconsole;
      
      function init() {
        airconsole = new AirConsole({ orientation: "portrait" });

        airconsole.onConnect = function(device_id) {
          if (airconsole.getMasterControllerDeviceId() === airconsole.device_id) {
            configureMaster();
          } else {
            configureClient();
          }
        }

        airconsole.onDisconnect = function (device_id) {
          if (airconsole.getMasterControllerDeviceId() === airconsole.device_id) {
            configureMaster();
          } else {
            configureClient();
          }
        }

        const configureClient = () => {
          document.getElementById("game_output").innerHTML = "You are one of the additional players";
        }
        const configureMaster = () => {
          document.getElementById("game_output").innerHTML = "You are the controlling player";
        }
        airconsole.onReady = () => {     
          if (airconsole.getMasterControllerDeviceId() === airconsole.device_id) {
            configureMaster();
          } else {
            configureClient();
          }
        };

        airconsole.onCustomDeviceStateChange = (device_id, data) => {
          if (airconsole.getMasterControllerDeviceId() === airconsole.device_id) {
            configureMaster();
          } else {
            configureClient();
          }
        };

    </script>
   
    <div id="game_output">... Waiting for Screen ...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing? The first player currently has a play button. If he presses this button, the controller comes up, but the second player does not, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you building your game based on any of our examples?
If not I would probably need to see the code on how you implement your controller(s)  and how your screen.html looks like (if web, otherwise what your Unity logic is)

Comment: Normally you will want to send a message from the Master Controller that then is received by your Screen / Unity Game.
The Screen / Unity game then will execute the change and inform all players about it either using a broadcast or using a custom device state property, depending on what the change is (just something that happens or did the actual state change, like start screen to menu, menu to character selection and so on)

Comment: Can you show me how to send a message from screen.html to controller.html ?

Comment: Is there a way to send a controller.html message from the unity game logic code?

Comment: That is absolutely possible. The Pong Example in the AirConsole Unity Plugin shows the simplest possible usage of this.
In Controller.html https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-unity-plugin/blob/master/Assets/AirConsole/examples/pong/controller.html#L64 you see how the controller sends a message to Unity (which represents the screen, so you use AirConsole.SCREEN)

Comment: In Unity you will then receive this message through the `AirConsole.instance.onMessage` event by listening for it (https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-unity-plugin/blob/3aeb91225295bb493693870c89cf8077fbe0d5ad/Assets/AirConsole/examples/pong/ExamplePongLogic.cs#L20C3-L20C32) and implementing message parsing (https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-unity-plugin/blob/3aeb91225295bb493693870c89cf8077fbe0d5ad/Assets/AirConsole/examples/pong/ExamplePongLogic.cs#L66C12-L66C12)